my template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
I have a problem, my template code (thymealeaf) is stored in the database, and my project is to call the template from the database and convert it to pdf using itext7.
Here's my code:
public void editerMyAttestationLangue() throws BOException {
        final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

        LangueTemplate idLangue = new LangueTemplate();
        idLangue.setId(1L);

        TypeTemplate idTypeTemplate = new TypeTemplate();
        idTypeTemplate.setId(301L);

        TemplateHtml templateHtml = templateHtmlServiceImpl.getTemplateHtmlByIdLangueIdTypeTemplate(idLangue, idTypeTemplate);

        if (templateHtml != null) {
            String fichierTemplate = templateHtml.getFichierTemplate();
            if (fichierTemplate != null) {
                System.out.println("Template récupéré : " + fichierTemplate);

                
                String htmlContent = processTemplateWithModel(templateContent);

                byte[] pdfBytes = convertMyHtmlToPdf(htmlContent);
                loadMyEditionPDF(response, pdfBytes, templateHtml.getDescription() + ".pdf");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Le fichier template est vide ou null.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Aucun template trouvé pour les paramètres spécifiés.");
        }
    }

    private String processTemplateWithModel(String templateContent) {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("emetteur", "yassine");
       

        return templateengine.process(templateContent, context);
    }

    private byte[] convertMyHtmlToPdf(String htmlContent) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer = null;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = null;
        Document document = null;

        try {
            writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
            pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

            // Pied de page
            String footerContent = "Siège social";
            FooterHandler footerHandler = new FooterHandler(footerContent);
            pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, footerHandler);

            // En-tête
            String imagePath = "/src/main/resources/imagesEdition/logo.png";
            HeaderHandler headerHandler = new HeaderHandler(imagePath);
            pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, headerHandler);

            document = new Document(pdfDoc);

            if (htmlContent == null || htmlContent.trim().isEmpty()) {
                document.add(new Paragraph("Contenu HTML est vide ou null. Ajout d'une page par défaut."));
            } else {
                ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
                HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent.getBytes("UTF-8")), pdfDoc, converterProperties);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("IOException lors de la conversion du HTML en PDF : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Exception générale lors de la conversion du HTML en PDF : " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (document != null) {
                    document.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println("Exception lors de la fermeture du document : " + e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                if (pdfDoc != null) {
                    pdfDoc.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println("Exception lors de la fermeture du PdfDocument : " + e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println("Exception lors de la fermeture du PdfWriter : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    public void loadMyEditionPDF(HttpServletResponse response, byte[] byteData, String nameFile) throws BOException {
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + nameFile + "\"");
        try (OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream()) {
            output.write(byteData);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new BOException("Problème lors de l'édition", e);
        }
    }

when I test with a static template it works, but when I test with a dynamic template I get the following error message:

template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the
configured Template Resolvers

My HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bonjour tout le monde</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello <span " th:text="${emetteur}"></h1>
</body>
</html>

when I use break point, it given an error here:
String htmlContent = processTemplateWithModel(templateContent);

